# What is name of this part on a helicopter?

Tags: helicopter, feature-identification, airframe

What is name of this highlighted part of helicopter and what is its use?

[image]

Comment: Guessing angle-of-attack sensor combined with sideslip sensor, i.e. a vane that pivots in 2 axes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this cutaway](https://i.etsystatic.com/10464274/r/il/8f7c74/3613980507/il_fullxfull.3613980507_sbqy.jpg) it is called "*low speed omnidirectional air data sensor system probe*". Albeit overcomplicated, the name should be anyway self explaining.

The helicopter in the picture is a [Bell AH-1 Cobra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_AH-1_Cobra) and, funnily enough, those kind of sensors are sometimes called *cobra probe* due to their shape.

Comment: Is it possible to know whether it is a pivoting vane (possibly in both pitch and yaw), or is fixed?

Comment: The round tail fin assembly tells you it's an articulating vane that weathervanes. It would almost certainly have freedom of movement vertically and laterally, allowing precise speed measurements at a range of yaw and pitch angles.